# Samba PDC - Create groups

Tags: domain, samba, groups

I'm researching on Samba and have created a PDC using it. I have created user and computer accounts and things are working.
I'm having problems, however, in finding how to create groups and add users to them. Samba apparently doesn't create AD default groups like "Domain Users" or "Domain Admins". Does it use Unix groups for that or I have to create them using some Samba tool?

Are these groups "searchable" in Windows workstations as users are (or like when using AD)?

I'm running CentOS 6.7 and Samba 3.6.23.

I'm using tdbsam to store user data.

Comment: What backend are you using to store users credentials? tdb/ldap/etc?

Comment: Regarding your edit: It is *far* better to include the new information in the question than in an edit - thus, no reason at all to apologize for doing so. @ALex_hha: answer to your comment is now included in the question.

Comment: Why are you testing an old, discontinued (for almost a year) version of Samba?  https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Release_Planning

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive search I managed to find how to do it. I just don't know why material explaining this rather common procedure is so scarce over the internet.

1 - Create an Unix group.

```
# groupadd domainusers
```

2 - Add users to the group. These are the Unix users that must be also created with smbpasswd.

```
# usermod -aG domainusers user1
# usermod -aG domainusers user2
```

3 - Use the command "net" to map the Unix group to a new Samba group.

```
# net groupmap add ntgroup="Domain Users" unixgroup=domainusers
```

Now you can find the group on a Windows workstation when changing file permissions or adding to a local group, for example.

I based this on what I found here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/samba_setup_ubuntu_5.10_p4